# Linphone doesn't work well on Wi-Fi network - Asterisk Server

Tags: sip, asterisk, linphone

I use Linphone(http://www.linphone.org/) open source to make a mVoIP android application using Asterisk Server. It is working nicely when the smartphone is on 3G or 4G(LTE) network. However, it failed to register when it is on Wi-Fi network.

Via and Contact info was wrong for smartphone that is on Wi-Fi network.

```
A = Smartphone on Wi-Fi network
B = Smartphone on 4G(LTE) network
```

It delivers sounds to B phone from A phone. However, it failed to deliver sound from B phone to A phone.

**I traced SIP logs and noticed that phone A tells wrong private IP address(contact) to Asterisk server.** It was why it failed to listen sound on phone A.

So, I turned on Stun server, which I have to connect specific stun server, it hardly finds local IP address through NAT. The problem was that Linphone itself cannot find a private IP address of smartphone A that is on Wi-Fi network.

```
C = A third smartphone on Wi-Fi network.
```

Another problem that I faced is that an additional smartphone on same Wi-Fi network is not working even though Stun server solved its NAT problem.

Is there anyone who had same issue? and is there a way to solve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have

1) enable STUN

2) in asterisk set directrtpsetup=no for BOTH peers.

Comment: Do I have to enable STUN all the time? I am using FreePBX and can't find directrtpsetup setup..

Comment: If you use client after NAT you need use STUN to help determine external ip. You can use canreinvite=yes in freepbx.

Comment: I've tried what you said, but it is same. I should use Stun server to hear sound, but it is unstable to connect at first time.

Comment: If you have problem with linphone, maybe you have try OTHER softphone or contact linphone's support maillist?